# Add second IP-address to interface in 17.10

Tags: networking, ifconfig, netplan

How do I add a second IP-address in Ubuntu 17.10 like the old days where you could add eth0:1, eth0:2 etc.

I've tried but lots of commands have been deprecated like ifup, ifdown etc. and the network settings doesn't seem to be the same as it used to.
I might be wrong here but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a network card **eth0** where I want to add a second IP on the same subnet.
If I add eth0:1 to **/etc/network/interfaces** but I can't seem to get the interface up.

Is there another way to do this permanently?

EDIT:

**/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.100.1.39
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I've tried to add the information on **eth0** too but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

This if the output of **ifconfig**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.100.1.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.100.1.255
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:1605  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:5d:00:16:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 496  bytes 248506 (248.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 241  bytes 34934 (34.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: I don't know, but I recall having to recompile the kernel with a flag set to enable the virtual-interfaces for ports; but its been too long since i required it..

Comment: could you post your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and the output  of `ifconfig eth0`?

Comment: I doubt that the interface is eth0 in 17.10.

Comment: @pim I have edited my post with the information.

Comment: @chili555 no it's eth0. Why do you doubt that?

Comment: Because of this: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: @chili555 [udev's persistent net-rules](http://fewstreet.com/2015/06/09/ubuntu-udev-naming-rules.html) for the win !

Comment: @RobertRiedl Wow! That's a lot of trouble to resist the inevitable march of progress!

Comment: @chili555, usually that's one line of code per interface. Not that bad, I think, especially if you upgrade from the "old" naming convention to the "new" naming convention.  Also, the nice thing is, for example if you add/remove or enable/disable a bunch of (virtual) interfaces, you can tell your OS beforehand what they should be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out in 17.10 you edit your network settings in **/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

All I had to do was add the second IP next to the existing one separated with a comma like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
     addresses: [ 10.100.1.38/24, 10.100.1.39/24 ]
     gateway4: 10.100.1.1
```

Then you run:

```
# netplan apply
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: ..isn't that the network manager's files ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That's correct; you can add as many addresses for an interface as necessary by adding to the "addresses" list this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that directly on the commandline, which is not permanent (i.e. reboot-save)

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 10.100.1.40 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

or in your `/etc/network/interfaces`, which is permanent

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

add this (or similar) to the existing `eth0` block

```
iface eth0:0 inet static
  address 10.100.1.40
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and bring it up with

```
sudo ifup eth0:0
```

Comment: I don't know whats unclear in my first post but that's pretty much exactly what I did and it doesn't seem to work in 17.10 anymore,  hence my post about netplan that seems to be the new way to configure network. See here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan

Comment: What's your error message ? Because it works on my system and *should* work on yours

Comment: Did you upgrade from an earlier version maybe? Because they seem to have changed it in 17.10 as the old way doesn't work on a fresh install. I've always used Debian before and have used the "old" way for years so I was a little confused when it didn't work anymore.

Comment: No its a pretty fresh install (2 months old). As the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan) states its for NetworkManager and systemd, though it doesn't support a whole lot.  What I'd like to know: If you use this `sudo ifconfig eth0:0 10.100.1.40 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` on the commandline, is the exitcode 0 ? what does `ip a` say ?

Comment: Tested the /etc/network/interface method on 18.04, it seems to work, after spending 3 full minutes on "Starting hostname service"

Comment: @pim, on 18.04 you might need to use `ip` instead of `ifconfig`. Try `ip addr add 10.100.1.40/24 dev eth0`

Comment: My comment was about the the /etc/network/interface method. The ifconfig method works on 18.04... Sure we should use `ip` for something like 10 years now, but the ifconfig still works

Comment: @pim, if you add it in the `interfaces`file, what was the output of `ifup eth0:0` afterwards?

Comment: @RobertRiedl : (still testing on 18.04) takes 10-15 seconds but works as expected.